# How to clear "Results" from Proc Univariate to show only a specific table

Tags: sas, statistics, distribution, resultset, proc

I´ve been using the UNIVARIATE proccedure in order to get the p-value from a series of distributions (lognormal, exponential, gamma) and have reached the following problem:

I am using the following code to get the p-values of the goodness of fit tests for each of the distributions:

```
ods select all/*ParameterEstimates GoodnessOfFit*/;
proc univariate data=results.Parametros_Prueba_1;
      var Monto_1.;
      histogram /
      lognormal (l=1  color=red SHAPE=&ParamLOGN2_1  SCALE=&ParamLOGN1_1)
      gamma (l=1  color=red    SHAPE=&ParamGAM1_1 SCALE=&ParamGAM2_1)
      exponential   (l=2 SCALE=&ParamEXP1_1);
ods output GoodnessOfFit=results.Goodness_1;
run;

proc print data=results.Goodness_1;
```

After running the previous code I get the "Results" which gives me the histogram graphic and other descriptive information about the tests. I am looking for a way to get this "Results" print to show only the last part corresponding to the "proc print" added on the last line.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The ODS SELECT is the standard method, but I see you've commented that part out, so can we assume that this didn't work?

Comment: Hi @Reeza ! yes, unfortunately it gives the data partitioned for each distribution. On the other hand the "GoodnessOfFit" table gives the summary of these tables...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want no output to the screen (results window) from `PROC UNIVARIATE`, then the simplest answer is:

```
ods select none;
proc univariate ... ;
run;
ods select all;
proc print ... ;
run;
```

`ods select none;` tells ODS to not make any ODS output whatsoever.  You'll still get your ODS OUTPUT though as that comes in afterwards.

```
ods select none;
proc univariate data=sashelp.class;
  var height;
      histogram name='univhist' /
      lognormal (l=1  color=red  )
      gamma (l=1  color=red    )
      exponential   (l=2  );
ods output GoodnessOfFit=Goodness_1;
run;
ods select all;
proc print data=Goodness_1;
run;
```

Now, you'll note you don't get your histogram; that one is harder.  It unfortunately changes its name every time you run it, and even if you use the NAME= option, that'll only work the first time it's run.  You need to use `PROC GREPLAY` to delete it.

```
proc greplay nofs igout=work.gseg;
  delete 'univhist';
run; quit;
```

(Assuming `UNIVHIST` is the name you assign it.)

Comment: Thanks Joe! that did it!